# Why am I getting a security sandbox violation?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am running a project locally. My project is trying to access a file on MYDOMAIN. I am getting the following error:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'MYDOMAIN/system/components/compimg/11852997eab43ff5c7b1803692bee608/pattern' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///C:/Users/myusername/Documents/Flex%20Builder%203/myproject/bin-debug/Works.html'
```

In the root of MYDOMAIN, I have a crossdomain.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please remove the doctype in the crossdomain.xml. When running locally, it should not be a problem. unless you are running the flex app in the server with localhost. Make sure the crossdomain is accessible without any auth issues. try to open it from the webbrowser.

Comment: I tried removing the doctype in the crossdomain.xml. I can access it through the web browser without any issues.

Comment: You can load the policy file manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527911/flex-load-policy-file-crossdomain-xml check this.

Comment: I tried that.. it then gave me the same "Security Sandbox Violation" and referenced the crossdomain.xml file